# Creating a table from two queries, error with "WITH" clause

Tags: sql-server-2008

Good Morning!

I am trying to combine two queries to make a table. (Please see code below)

```
`CREATE TABLE Layer_Loss
(
    dYear            INT     NOT    NULL,
    EventNum     INT     NOT NULL,
    Loss             INT     NULL,
    Rec_L1           BIGINT  NULL,
    Rec_L2           BIGINT  NULL,
    Rec_L3           BIGINT  NULL,
    Cap_CML_L1   BIGINT  NULL,
    Cap_CML_L2   BIGINT  NULL,
    Cap_CML_L3   BIGINT  NULL,


)
INSERT INTO Layer_Loss (dYear,EventNum, Loss, Rec_L1, Rec_L2, Rec_L3, Capped_CML_L1, Capped_CML_L2, Capped_CML_L3)


WITH c AS (SELECT Row_number() OVER (ORDER BY dYear) AS rownum,* 
    FROM Layer_Loss_Capped2)
SELECT *
    FROM
    (
    SELECT dYear, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (Partition by dYear Order by dYear) as Event_Number, Loss
    , 'Recovery_L1'=CASE
    WHEN Loss<10000000 THEN 0
    WHEN Loss<30000000 THEN 20000000-(30000000-Loss) 
    ELSE 20000000 
    END
    , 'Recovery_L2'=CASE
    WHEN Loss<30000000 THEN 0
    WHEN Loss<60000000 THEN 30000000-(60000000-Loss) 
    ELSE 30000000 
    END
    , 'Recovery_L3'=CASE
    WHEN Loss<60000000 THEN 0
    WHEN Loss<100000000 THEN 40000000-(100000000-Loss) 
    ELSE 40000000 
    END
    , (SELECT *, 'Capped_CML_L1'=CASE 
            WHEN d.CML_L1>40000000 THEN 4000000 
            ELSE d.CML_L1
            END
    , (SELECT *, 'Capped_CML_L2'=CASE 
            WHEN d.CML_L2>60000000 THEN 6000000 
            ELSE d.CML_L1
            END
    , (SELECT *, 'Capped_CML_L3'=CASE 
            WHEN d.CML_L1>80000000 THEN 8000000 
            ELSE d.CML_L1
            END
    FROM
    (
    SELECT a.dYear, a.EventNum, a.Loss, a.Rec_L1, SUM(b.Rec_L1) AS CML_L1, SUM(b.Rec_L2) AS  CML_L2, SUM(b.Rec_L3) as CML_L3
    FROM c a
    LEFT JOIN c b ON a.dYear = b.dYear AND b.rownum <= a.rownum 
    GROUP BY a.dYear, a.rownum, a.EventNum, a.Rec_L1, a.Loss
    ) AS d
    ) AS e
    FROM ['04_AIR_StdHU_DS_noSS_ByTerr$']
    ) AS a

DROP TABLE Layer_Loss`
```

I have it so that the query about 'Recovery_L1', 'Recovery_L2', and 'Recovery_L3' are about of table "Layer_Loss", which I've called "Rec_L1", "Rec_L2", and "Rec_L3". When I try to add the query that leads to "Capped_CML_L1", "Capped_CML_L2", and "Capped_CML_L3" I get the following error:

"Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 14
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'WITH'.
Msg 319, Level 15, State 1, Line 14
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'with'. If this statement is a common table expression, an xmlnamespaces clause or a change tracking context clause, the previous statement must be terminated with a semicolon."

I have tried moving 'WITH' clause around but end up with the same result.

Also, this is not my end result. My next step would be to subtract the current row from the previous row from the columns "Capped_CML_L1", "Capped_CML_L2", and "Capped_CML_L3" into a column called "Inc_Rec_L1", "Inc_Rec_L2", and "Inc_Rec_L3". I was thinking about using a cursor, but I have never used one before, so if you have any suggestions on this, that would be great too!

Thank you for your help!

EDIT:

```
`CREATE TABLE Layer_Loss
(
    dYear            INT     NOT    NULL,
    EventNum     INT     NOT NULL,
    Loss             INT     NULL,
    Rec_L1           BIGINT  NULL,
    Rec_L2           BIGINT  NULL,
    Rec_L3           BIGINT  NULL,
    Cap_CML_L1   BIGINT  NULL,
    Cap_CML_L2   BIGINT  NULL,
    Cap_CML_L3   BIGINT  NULL,


)


;WITH c AS (SELECT Row_number() OVER (ORDER BY dYear) AS rownum,* 
    FROM Layer_Loss_Capped2)

INSERT INTO Layer_Loss (dYear,EventNum, Loss, Rec_L1, Rec_L2, Rec_L3, Capped_CML_L1, Capped_CML_L2, Capped_CML_L3)


SELECT *
    FROM
    (
    SELECT dYear, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (Partition by dYear Order by dYear) as Event_Number, Loss
    , 'Recovery_L1'=CASE
    WHEN Loss<10000000 THEN 0
    WHEN Loss<30000000 THEN 20000000-(30000000-Loss) 
    ELSE 20000000 
    END
    , 'Recovery_L2'=CASE
    WHEN Loss<30000000 THEN 0
    WHEN Loss<60000000 THEN 30000000-(60000000-Loss) 
    ELSE 30000000 
    END
    , 'Recovery_L3'=CASE
    WHEN Loss<60000000 THEN 0
    WHEN Loss<100000000 THEN 40000000-(100000000-Loss) 
    ELSE 40000000 
    END
    , (SELECT *, 'Capped_CML_L1'=CASE 
            WHEN d.CML_L1>40000000 THEN 4000000 
            ELSE d.CML_L1
            END
    , (SELECT *, 'Capped_CML_L2'=CASE 
            WHEN d.CML_L2>60000000 THEN 6000000 
            ELSE d.CML_L1
            END
    , (SELECT *, 'Capped_CML_L3'=CASE 
            WHEN d.CML_L1>80000000 THEN 8000000 
            ELSE d.CML_L1
            END
    FROM
    (
    SELECT a.dYear, a.EventNum, a.Loss, a.Rec_L1, SUM(b.Rec_L1) AS CML_L1, SUM(b.Rec_L2) AS  CML_L2, SUM(b.Rec_L3) as CML_L3
    FROM c a
    LEFT JOIN c b ON a.dYear = b.dYear AND b.rownum <= a.rownum 
    GROUP BY a.dYear, a.rownum, a.EventNum, a.Rec_L1, a.Loss
    ) AS d
    FROM ['04_AIR_StdHU_DS_noSS_ByTerr$']
) AS e
) AS f
) AS g
) AS a

DROP TABLE Layer_Loss`
```

When I put in the above edited code I get error:
Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 58
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'FROM'.

I would like to be able to reference Capped_CML_L1, Capped_CML_L2, and Capped_CML_L3 in another query or table or cursor later on. I wanted it to be under just 'e' but I'm not sure how with the parentheses

Answer (score 0):

[`WITH`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175972%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) must be separated from any preceding command by a `;`.

> When a CTE is used in a statement that is part of a batch, the statement before it must be followed by a semicolon.

Also, it must be the first part of the entire statement it's a part of, whether that be a plain `SELECT` or an [`INSERT`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174335.aspx). Try:

```
/* CREATE TABLE */

;WITH c AS (SELECT Row_number() OVER (ORDER BY dYear) AS rownum,* 
    FROM Layer_Loss_Capped2)
INSERT INTO Layer_Loss (dYear,EventNum, Loss, Rec_L1, Rec_L2, Rec_L3,
                  Capped_CML_L1, Capped_CML_L2, Capped_CML_L3)
SELECT *
    FROM
    (
    SELECT dYear, ROW_NUMBER() OVER ...
```

(Have also moved the `WITH` before the `INSERT`, having realised what was being attempted)

See also [Transact SQL Syntax conventions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177563.aspx):

> `;` Transact-SQL statement terminator.Although the semicolon is not required for most statements in this version of SQL Server, it will be required in a future version.

One of the main reasons for this is that there is a pre-existing use for the keyword `WITH` that modifies `SELECT` statements. By insisting on the `;`, it makes the parse a lot easier.

Comment: Thank you! That worked, however now I am getting the following message: "Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 62
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'DROP'."

Comment: @user2505578 - I think that you're rather short on the correct number of `)`s. Just did a quick crude attempt to work it out.

Comment: You are right, I just noticed this too. Let me show you what I have now in my question

Comment: @user2505578 - taking everything in your select statement and removing everything that isn't a bracket produces this: `(()()()()()((((()()())))` which I think is missing two `)`s to be balanced. Where they're correctly to be inserted into your query I'll leave to you (try breaking the query up into smaller parts, possibly introducing more Common Table Expressions)

Comment: The  FROM    ['04_AIR_StdHU_DS_noSS_ByTerr$']
is for the 'Recovery_L1','Recovery_L2', and 'Recovery_L3'